# Binaries for cpp-netlib

Tags: c++, network-programming, cpp-netlib

I would like to know if it is possible to get the binaries for the static library for windows (x86 and x64) now present in cpp-netlib for the version 0.9.1?

Frankly it is a pain to compile this on windows for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that cpp-netlib is a header-only library, although it relies on some boost compiled libraries, such as Boost.System, Boost.Date_time, and Boost.Regex.  You can easily find boost pre-compiled libraries all over the Internet.  You will also need the boost headers to be in your build path as well.  Even though cpp-netlib says that Boost 1.41.0 will do, in actuality, version 0.9.1 requires Boost version 1.46.0 or later (just grab the latest which is 1.47.0).

You could also try defining BOOST_NETWORK_NO_LIB which should help out.

Comment: Thanks, I gave up on compiling it yesterday and used the macro instead, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

New version's of cpp-netlib now do require building. I have answered how to build it on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088277/using-cpp-netlib-in-a-c-project-under-windows)

Comment: Hi Simon,

Is it possible to compile the cpp-netlib without using cmake...?
I am confused with this statement from getting started doc:
"f you intend to run the test suite, you can follow the instructions below. Otherwise, you don’t need CMake to use cpp-netlib in your project. The cpp-netlib requires CMake version 2.8 or higher."

Does that means I need not to have cmake to really use cpp-netlib ?

Comment: I have looked at the project for the first time in years. I know a bit more about cmake now, and if you want a VC++ project, you are going to need cmake.