# Using cpp-netlib in a C++ project under Windows

Tags: c++, cpp-netlib

I want to use the cpp-netlib library in a C++ project of mine running on Windows. 
I've strictly followed the instructions under http://cpp-netlib.github.com/getting_started.html up to the "Getting CMake" section, which is where
I stopped understanding the instruction. Is CMake indeed non-obligatory? If so, what are the exact steps required so I can use the library in my projects?

If someone could provide me with instructions here, or refer me to a detailed guide it'd be
great. Google didn't help me that much.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I am trying to use this too.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Eventually we used a different technology.

Comment: Updated [link to the latest getting started guide](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.10.1/getting_started.html#getting-started).

Answer (score 9):

Same problem here:

I got it going with

From the directory I dumped cpp-netlib-0.9.4 in

```
cd ..
mkdir cpp-netlib-build
cd cpp-netlib-build
cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 10" -DBOOST_ROOT:string="C:\Dev\Boost\boost_1_51_0" ../cpp-netlib-0.9.4
```

(Your paths may vary)
This populates the cpp-netlib-build directory with a VS10 solution and projects.

Comment: I really liked cpp-netlib's use of Boost, and the structure of it's API, but due to bugs I opted for [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) in the end.

Comment: Instead of -DBOOST_ROOT:string I had to specify -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR:string and -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR:string separately. Also, -G "Visual Studio 11" worked with VS2012.

Comment: The generated VS projects did not specify the BOOST_LIBRARYDIR as an additional library folder, I had to add it manually to all project.